# Prob in testing Blackberry App in device: Secure API prob

Tags: security, api, blackberry, signature

I have developed a Blackberry app in Blackberry JDE. It is working fine in simulator. As I have used different API which need signing key, I try it to 'Signature Tool' so that I can run it in device. Initially the Signature Tool was showing like below.

[image]

When I 'Request' for signature, all the row having 'Not Signed' status, successfully converted to 'Signed'.

[image]

Now when I install the app in my Blackberry device and try to run it, it gives massage "Error starting Certainteed: Module 'Certainteed' attempts to access a secure API.". I think this massage should come only for not signed Cod file. Is there any problem in my signing process?

N.B. I am using Blackberry JDE 4.6 and Blackberry Curve 8520 (software version 4.6.1.286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if you haven't installed all of your signing keys, only the RBB signing key.

When you requested your signing keys you should have received 3 emails in response, each containing a different signing key:

```
client-RBB-xxxxxxxxx.csi
client-RCR-xxxxxxxxx.csi
client-RRT-xxxxxxxxx.csi
```

You need to install all 3 keys